# MDT windows 10 deployment error

Tags: windows, deployment, mdt

I continue to get errors when deploying win10 via MDT and I am kind of stumped on why i continue to get these issues i've attached the screenshot of the error and the log files I pulled from my machine.

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sb6zestvnjt26za/AADPUVUJ3FItXp_AvgQHh9pha?dl=0

Comment: Can you include / review your smsts.log file from the client? That's where I find most of the answers with a 0x8004005.. Likely a driver issue.

Comment: Here is the link for the smsts.log file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3bqu95dzjb62dn/smsts.log?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Based on your smsts.log file you are getting a 80070002 downloading the os files. This is a classic example of not having a working NIC driver in the image. Pressing F8 in the bot and running an ipconfig /all should verify this.

Ive also seen similar behavior if you need a certificate to access the distribution point but don't have one installed.